# jQuery fade next image in

Tags: jquery

I have this script that allows the user to click a thumbnail which changes the main image above.

```
$('#thumbs img').first().addClass('activeThumbnail');
$('#thumbs').delegate('img', 'click', function () {
    $('#largeImage').attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace('thumb', 'large'));
    $('#thumbs img').removeClass('activeThumbnail');
    $(this).addClass('activeThumbnail')
});
```

The 1st, 4th and last line deal with highlighting the current thumbnail that is being shown as the main image, so lines 2 and 3 and the bread and butter of the image swapping function.

I'd really like to change it just a little so that the next image that is being show fades in a little rather than being immediate, I have played around with adding .fadeIn in all manner of places but to no avail.

In case you need the HTML here it is:

```
<div id="bannerInner">
    <!--main image-->
    <div id="mainImage">
        <img id="largeImage" src="Images/banner/banner1_large.jpg">
        <img src="Images/banner/banner2_large.jpg">
        <img src="Images/banner/banner3_large.jpg">
        <img src="Images/banner/banner4_large.jpg">
        <img src="Images/banner/banner5_large.jpg">
        <img src="Images/banner/banner6_large.jpg">
        <img src="Images/banner/banner7_large.jpg">
    </div>
    <!--main image-->
</div>
<!--/banner inner-->
<!--banner filmstrip-->
<div id="bannerStrip">
    <!--thumbnail images-->
    <div id="thumbs">
        <ul class="carousel">
            <li>
                <img src="Images/banner/banner1_thumb.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="Images/banner/banner2_thumb.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="Images/banner/banner3_thumb.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="Images/banner/banner4_thumb.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="Images/banner/banner5_thumb.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="Images/banner/banner6_thumb.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="Images/banner/banner7_thumb.jpg" />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Any help really appreciated :)

gb

Comment: could you make a jsfiddle for us?

Comment: Hi Mike, just made one, its like this fiddle (but not exact) so click on a thumb and image changes instantly, I'd like it to fade in each time a thumb is clicked http://jsfiddle.net/aHVNy/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`fadeOut`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) complete function:

> A function to call once the animation is complete.

and when it happens change the image href and `fadeIn` it.

Code:

```
$('#thumbs').delegate('img', 'click', function () {
    var $this=$(this);
    $('#largeImage').fadeOut(1000, function () {
        $('#largeImage').attr('src', $this.attr('src').replace('thumb', 'large'));
        $('#thumbs img').removeClass('activeThumbnail'); //remove class from all thumbnails
        $this.addClass('activeThumbnail'); //add it to the clicked one
        $('#largeImage').fadeIn();
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/U2yR3/

### UPDATE

Instead of overlap all the images you can initially hide them using css:

```
#mainImage>img{
    display: none;
}
#mainImage>img:first-child {
    display: inline !important;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/U2yR3/1/

Comment: Hi Irvin, looking at your fiddle when you click a thumb the last image fades in every time then just as it ends fading the actual thumb you clicked on gets shown, it looks weird :)

Comment: @Geoff it's because how the images are stacked, check the edit

Comment: Hi Irvin, almost there, your altered fiddle now fades out current image then bangs in new image once its gone. Anyway of getting the next image to just fade in on top?

Comment: I think perfection would have been to have previous image visible then fade in image clicked over it but I'm sure this would take a little more work. I am happy enough with this solution. thank you very much for your time. Not to look closely at your code, try to understand it so I can improve for the future :)

Comment: @Geoff I'll take a look at it, glad to help you; if answer your question consider to mark/upvote the answer